# Emac lisp: run scritp in shell. How remove "Mark set"

Tags: elisp

To start my emacs lisp script from shell, I use the next command:

**emacs --script my-script.el -f my-function**

And it's work OK. But when script is running on shell it's print text '**Mark set**' many times. How I can remove this text?

Answer (score 0):

Pass `NOMSG` to `push-mark`

(Did you write the script yourself? It sounds like you did, but if so then I'm confused that you didn't check the documentation for the mark-related functions you're calling.)

Answer (score 0):

I fix the problem. In my script I use command "*beginning-of-buffer*" that use function "*push-mark*". As result it print "**Mark set**".
So I replace "*beginning-of-buffer*" by "*(goto-char (point-min))*" and "**Mark set**" not print anymore.

P.S. In elisp documentation:

"*beginning-of-buffer*" - **Don't use this command in Lisp programs!**